# I need to write in a text file user's data in a json format so latter i can read them,but is not working.

Tags: android, json

I am buidling and android game, which should store user's name and score on the game everytime he or someone else plays the game.
So I need to save the data in a json file cause latter I want to read the file and show them on the screen.
When file is created and I want to add append json content on it, it doest work.

```
    public void writeToJsonfile(String name, int scoreForBasketGame) 
    throws 
    JSONException, IOException {
      String jsonFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/" + "usersScoreOnBasketGame.txt";
    File file = new File(jsonFile);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject tempObj = new JSONObject();
        tempObj.put("Name", name);
        tempObj.put("scoreForBasketGame", scoreForBasketGame);
        jsonArray.put(tempObj);
        try (FileWriter newfile = new FileWriter(jsonFile)) {
            newfile.write(jsonArray.toString());
        }
    }
     else {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("File error", "Cant read the file");
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(text.toString());
        JSONObject objToAdd = new JSONObject();
        objToAdd.put("Name", name);
        objToAdd.put("scoreForBasketGame", scoreForBasketGame);
        jsonArray.put(objToAdd);
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
        filewriter.write(String.valueOf(jsonArray));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to store the data in a JSON file? Android provides more sophisticated and ready to use options https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: What do you suggest me? I know the storage options of android, but I am thinking to use json as it's easier to work with it, and I dont think that a sql database is necessary

Answer (score -1):

I do something very similar to save in a .txt file info than can´t be sync with remote dataBase, i strongly recomend to use gson (look for gson depedency and implement in your project) to parse the object to json and save it.

```
 public void userToFile(List<User> data){
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (User user : data) {
            jsonArray.add(gson.toJson(user));
        }
        Log.i("JSON",jsonArray.toString());
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"name of your file" + ".txt");
        Log.i("PATH_FILE",Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
        try {
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(jsonArray.toString());
            output.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you want to save just one user, changue JsonArray to JsonObject and use the same logic. This save the text file in the external download folder and don't forget to implement the permission for this task in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```